# Proof on triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I've already seen that this is true visually(I made a sketch), but I don't know how to write it formally to prove it...I'm studying geometry formally for the first time.

QUESTION: If $\overline {AB} \cong \overline {DE},\overline {AC} \cong \overline {DF}, \angle CBA \cong \angle FED$, but $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEF$ aren't congruent, prove that if $|CB|\lt|EF|$ then $\angle BCA \gt 90$.

Any tips?

Comment: Can you post the sketch?

Comment: @JohnGlenn I can't right now. I drew triangle EDF(base EF) with angle FED being an acute angle. Then I drew triangle BAC(base BC) and I rotated the side AC to the left, until |BC|<|EF| and angle BCA is obviously obtuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I managed to solve this! I came up with this drawing when I saw @idk answer.
Since $\triangle ACF$ is isosceles we have that $\angle FCA =\angle CFA$.
If $\angle BCA=90$ then $\angle FCA=90,$ but then $\angle CFA=90$, which is a contradiction since the sum of the angles of a triangle is $\leq180$. If $\angle BCA<90$ then $\angle FCA\gt90$, but then $\angle CFA\gt90$, which is a contradiction for the same reason. In conclusion it must be $\angle BCA\gt90.$

Answer (score 1):

Draw triangles $ABC,DEF$. Locate C' on EF such that C'E=BC. Now prove that triangles $ABC,DEC'$ are congruent and then solve the rest.

[image]

Comment: This was useful, but it's not what I'm looking for. I haven't yet reached the theorem that says that the angles of a triangle sum to 180. I only proved that the sum of the angles of a triangle are at most 180. But I would be happy with this proof when I reach there, but there's one thing that is bugging me, how do you justify that a<90? Just by looking at the triangle?

Comment: . In $\triangle DC′F$ we have 2 angles which are α which means maximum value of α is $90^∘$. Observe that maximum sum of angles in a triangle can be $180^{\circ}$ then sum of all angles in $C'FD$ is between $0$ and $180$ which itself proves that $\alpha$ is atleast $90^{\circ}$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Notice that as $EF > BC$, exists $G$ such that $m(EG)=m(BC)$.

Then, by SAS, $ABC \cong DEG$ and we have that $m(DG)=m(AC)$, and the angles $BCA \cong DGE$

Now, the triangle $DGF$ is isosceles, then $DGF \cong DFG$.

If, $BCA \le 90$ follows that $DGF \ge 90$ because they are supplementary.

And we have a triangle $DGF$ with two obtuse\right angles, a contradicition. (Why?)

Notice that this result is true in any Neutral Geometry

Comment: I think your 2nd figure is wrong, but your answer gave me an idea and I managed to prove this! I will post it.